# CSS - Center Tables inside A div + Tables "Breaks" his Row Horizontal

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I'm trying for days now to center table, and I JUST CAN'T get it done.

For some unknown reason the `margin-right:auto` and margin `left:auto` will not center it Inside the ***DIV*** !

I made it responsive for mobile "ugly" way using specific margin at @media lol.
It's should be simple but i just cant understand why it won't center itself and be responsive.

Another Problem- Should be simple.

That if I add an images above the table, it breaks down the table so it's look like that:

```
IMG
        TABLE   TABLE 
TABLE
```

Any suggestion on either?

Any suggestions?
Here is the Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">


table{
    text-align: center;
display:inline-table;
max-width: 33%;
height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15px;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
td,tr{

   padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
table img{

    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#cont table
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 max-width:300px;
 float: right;



}
#cont
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

max-width: 100%;


}
tr > td 
{

padding-bottom: 0.5em;


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 #cont
 {


    margin:60px;
 }


    }
</style></head>

<body>

<div id="cont">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="2.jpg"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>

 a
    </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>

        a
    </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        a

    </td>


   </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="2.jpg"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>

a   </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>

        a
    </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
 a          
    </td>


   </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            a
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>

 a      </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>

a   </td>


   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
a           </td>


   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `margin: auto;` won't work for `display: inline-table`. Anyway why you need `inline-table`? Just delete this line and check again. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if you want the 3 Tables next to each other and centered leave `inline-table` and try to add `text-align: center` to `#cont`

Comment: hmm for some reason it didnt work.. how do you keep remember all this rules? lol sometimes i just forget

Comment: Well it's practice and i don't remember everything but i know where i can look it up ;-) Try to get a devent understanding of CSS and it'll work. In the current case for example make sure you understand the difference beetween block-level and inline elements.

Comment: Thats' Awesome ! you might have skype that i can ask you some times quiestion that other people wont have enougfh knowledge? it would be awesome ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float:right` from `#cont table` . Align table to center by centering outer block like this:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBk42/5/)**

**CSS:**

```
  table {
    max-width: 33%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15px;
  }
 #cont table { 
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:300px;
    text-align: center;
  }

#cont {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Works ! The only this is when i decrease the window size to mobile size, all the text down the photos disappear, why is that? but it's work great thank you !!

Comment: might be you are having  #cont { margin:60px; } within media query.. just decrease the margin.. this might solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

change your `#cont` to this:

```
#cont {
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align:center; /*text-align:center here*/
    margin-right:auto;

    max-width: 100%;
    /*Removed the float:right;*/
}
```

works for me: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/2FXf6/)

Comment: Thats's worked either !! thak you 2 guys u r awesome !